# Rename Outlook Calendar item title

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way to easily rename the titles of Outlook Calendar items? Some of my items start with "FWD: " and I'd like to remove that from the title. I didn't find a "Rename" option when right-clicking on an item.

[image]

My Outlook version is "Outlook 2016".

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to easily rename the titles of Outlook Calendar items?

The following script will remove the `COPY:` prefix from calendar item titles.

It is a trivial exercise to modify this for your needs.

> **Use VBA to remove Copy**:
>
> Below is a VBA script you can use to cycle through every appointment
>   item in the selected calendar and remove the Copy: prefix. Works in
>   Outlook 2007 and 2010. (Also works in older versions, if you need to
>   mass-edit the subject line.)
>
> ```
> Sub RemoveCopy()  
> Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application  
> Dim calendar As MAPIFolder  
> Dim aItem As Object  
>
> Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  
> Set calendar = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder  
>
> Dim iItemsUpdated As Integer  
> Dim strTemp As String  
>
> iItemsUpdated = 0  
> For Each aItem In calendar.Items  
>     If Mid(aItem.Subject, 1, 6) = "Copy: " Then  
>       strTemp = Mid(aItem.Subject, 7, Len(aItem.Subject) - 6)  
>       aItem.Subject = strTemp  
>       iItemsUpdated = iItemsUpdated + 1  
>     End If  
>     aItem.Save  
> Next aItem  
>
> MsgBox iItemsUpdated & " of " & calendar.Items.Count & " Meetings Updated"  
>
> End Sub
> ```

Source [Copy: is prefixed to the Subject of a Meeting](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/copy-is-prefixed-meeting-subject/)

Answer (score 1):

Just single-click with a left mouse button on the desired title and it will switch to edit mode.